# Segmentation Fault for Expression Tree implementation in C

Tags: c, data-structures, segmentation-fault, binary-tree, expression-trees

C noob here,

I`'m trying to implement a C program to convert a POSTFIX expression into
a valid PREFIX expression by using an expression tree.

I created 2 files, a *TreeNode.h* file and a *main.c* file

TreeNode.h:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef char TreeEntry;

typedef struct treenode
{
    char entry;
    struct treenode * left;
    struct treenode * right;
}*TreeNode;


bool isOperator(char c)
{
    if (c == '+' || c == '-' ||
        c == '*' || c == '/' ||
        c == '^'){
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}


TreeNode newNode(TreeEntry v){
    TreeNode temp;
    temp->left = temp->right = 0;
    temp->entry = v;
    return temp;
}

void inOrder(TreeNode n){
    if(n){
        inOrder(n->left);
        printf("%s",n->entry);
        inOrder(n->right);
    }
}

void preOrder(TreeNode n){
    if(n){
        printf("%s",n->entry);
        preOrder(n->left);
        preOrder(n->right);
    }
}

void postOrder(TreeNode n){
    if(n){
        postOrder(n->left);
        postOrder(n->right);
        printf("%s",n->entry);
    }
}
```

main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "TreeNode.h"

#define MAXSTACK 50

TreeNode stack[MAXSTACK];
int top = -1;

void push(TreeNode n){
    stack[++top] = n;
}

TreeNode pop(){
    TreeNode n = stack[top--];
    return n;
}

TreeNode createExpTree(char postfix[]){
    TreeNode temp,et;
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(postfix); i++){
        if(!isOperator(postfix[i])){
            temp = newNode(postfix[i]);
            push(temp);
        }else{
            temp = newNode(postfix[i]);
            temp->right = pop();
            temp->left = pop();
            push(temp);
            printf("%c",temp->entry);
        }
    }

    et = pop();
    return et;
}

int main(void){
    char postfix[] = "ab+";
    TreeNode expTree = createExpTree(postfix);
    inOrder(expTree);
    preOrder(expTree);
    postOrder(expTree);
}
```

I keep getting *Segmentation fault* , I cant figure out whats causing this error.
How do I resolve this error ? please help.

**EDIT:**

I first changed the *newNode function* :

```
TreeNode * newNode(TreeEntry v){
    TreeNode * temp = (TreeNode *)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
    if(temp){
        temp->left = NULL;
        temp->right = NULL;
        temp->entry = v;
    }
    return temp;
}
```

even after this change I was still getting Segmentation fault error.

I managed to fix the error , apparently the error was in the *inorder* function in the TreeNode.h file

I changed the inorder function to:

```
void Inorder(TreeNode *root, void(*Visit)(TreeEntry x))
{
    if (root)
    {
        Inorder(root->left, Visit);
        Visit(root->entry);
        Inorder(root->right, Visit);
    }
}
```

and changed the main.c file :

```
void printEntry(TreeEntry te){
    printf("%c",te);
}


int main(void){
    char postfix[] = "ab+";
    TreeNode* expTree = createExpTree(postfix);
    Inorder(expTree,printEntry);
    
}
```

Now I'm assuming the previous inorder function was unable to access the values of the pointer that was passed to it, and that was what caused the error,

what is the reason for this ? I would be thankful if someone could give an explanation.

Comment: you should attempt to debug using gdb. Or step through the program using ```printf()``` statements to see where the code breaks.

Comment: Can you describe what you've tried? 
Compiling the code with warnings enable could provide you with useful insights like you're passing a `char` to `newNode` in `createExpTree` instead of `TreeNode`.

Also, I would recommend looking up how memory management works in C. Declaring a pointer doesn't allocate memory. You should look at dynamic memory allocation

Comment: `temp->left = pop();` I don't do `c` every day, but I'm surprised that this even compiles since `pop()` returns a `TreeNode` but `TreeNode.left` is declared as `struct treenode * left;`.

Comment: [_stack buffer underflow_](https://godbolt.org/z/eYbY1zbzP)

Comment: @NeonFire thankyou for the response. I used printf statements to debug the code, I managed to fix (see edit) the error and now the program is working as intended. Is the inorder function unable to access the values of the pointer that was passed to it. Is this the reason for the error

Answer (score 1):

I think the mistake lies in the newNode function. You declare the variable `temp`, as a `TreeNode`, which is the same as a `struct treenode *`. So that means you have a pointer, but you did not set it equal to anything, which means it just points to some random point in memory. So when you try to write to one of its variables, you're essentialy writing to memory that is not yours, causing a segmentation fault.

To fix this you need to allocate some memory, for your new node like this:

```
TreeNode newNode(TreeEntry v){
    TreeNode temp = (TreeNode)malloc(sizeof(struct treenode));
    temp->left = temp->right = 0;
    temp->entry = v;
    return temp;
}
```

Later on you need to use the `free` function to give this memory back to the operating system when you are done with it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer , I made the change that you mentioned. but I was still getting a segfault after it. After that I changed the inoder function and that fixed the segmentation fault and now the program works. I included the changes I made in the edit to my original post. Why is the previous inoder function unable to access the values of the pointer that was passed to it

Comment: I think it was because you use %s which means it expects a null-terminated string, but instead you gave it a char. Didn't your compiler give you a warning about that?